# string to date date formatting

Tags: swift, nsdateformatter

I am trying to convert string to date using NSDateFormatter,but some how I am not able to do.

Here is my code:

```
var dateformatter = NSDateFormatter() // object of NSDataFormatter
dateformatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-YYYY"  //Format in which I want date
println(dateformatter.dateFromString("2014-12-25 00:00:00"))
```

Comment: Why add to the thousands of questions on stack overflow that already answer this?

Comment: I want to convert NSString to NSDate @Fogmeister

Comment: Google gives me... https://www.google.co.uk/#safe=off&q=site:+www.stackoverflow.com+convert+nsstring+to+nsdate 172,000 results for "Convert NSString to NSDate". None of them were able to help you at all?

Comment: use "yyyy" instead "YYYY".

Answer (score 1):

Three things are wrong with the code; 1) year codes use lower case y's, 2) your date string is reversed, and 3) `dateFromString` returns an optional. I implicitly unwrapped the date here but you do the right thing as needed.

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
println(dateFormatter.dateFromString("25-12-2014")!)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this out :

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss"
let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString("25-12-2014 00:00:00")
println(date)
```

Edit: You should match 2014-12-25 to dd-MM-YYY like above.